# How to find and replace at a specific character in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, expression

I have this test:
`11814591, Anderson Rogerio Carleto, 125.73, 123.06, 17.50 
11270013, Andre Alexandre Moraes, 120.07, 117.66, 15.71 
11143569, Andre Andrade da Mota, 132.03,
129.06, 14.52`

And where have [, \n] I'd like to replace for only [, ], but I wasn't able to find [, ] and [\n] only could get one per time.

Someone could help me?

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick. In the *replace* field, it's one whitespace character.

```
Find: (?<=,)\n
Replace:
```

Output

```
11814591, Anderson Rogerio Carleto, 125.73, 123.06, 17.50 
11270013, Andre Alexandre Moraes, 120.07, 117.66, 15.71 
11143569, Andre Andrade da Mota, 132.03, 129.06, 14.52
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match:

`',\s*\n'`

and replace with:

`', '`

### Demo